# Set of accumulation points of a sequence and minimal or maximal element of a convergent sequence

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$. A number $ \alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ is called an accumulation point (or cluster point) of $(a_n)$ if for every $\varepsilon> 0$ the set $\{n \in \mathbb{N} : a_n \in U_{\varepsilon}(\alpha)\}$ contains infinitely many elements. Here, $U_{\varepsilon}(\alpha)$ denotes the open ball with centre $\alpha$ and radius $\varepsilon > 0$, i.e.,
$$
U_{\varepsilon}(\alpha) = \{ a \in \mathbb{R} : |a - \alpha| < \varepsilon\}.
$$
Denote by $H(a_n) = \{ \alpha \in \mathbb{R}: \alpha \text{ is accumulation point of } (a_n)\}$ the set of all accumulation points of the sequence $(a_n)$.

I have to show the following:

1. For every bounded sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ we have $\sup \{a_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}, \inf\{a_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\} \in \{a_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\} \cup H(a_n) $.
2. If $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is convergent, then the set $\{a_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ has a minimal or maximal element.

Hope, someone can help me

Comment: Hi gregor, if you find my answer is useful, may you give me an upvote? Thank you so much. :)

Comment: I'cant because my reputation is not high enough. Please give me an upvote. Then I can also give you an upvote :)

Comment: Lol I've done. :)

Comment: Now I have 13 points. But I need 15 points :D

Comment: You can give me an upvote to my other question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part $1$, if $\sup \{a_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ and $\inf \{a_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}\in \{a_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\},$ then we are done. So, we may assume that $\sup \{a_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}\notin \{a_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}.$ Then by the definition of supremum, we can find a subsequence whose limit is $\sup \{a_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ (**Think of this**). Similar argument applies to the infimum case.

For part $2$, if $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is convergent, then $H(a_n)$ contains only one point. By part $1$, at least one of $\sup \{a_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ and $\inf \{a_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ will be in $\{a_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}.$

Comment: Why can I find a subsequence whose limit is $\sup \{a_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$?

Comment: @gregor Bro, that’s your HW. Think of why.

Comment: Its not my Homework :). It is a remark in my textbook but without a proof. Hope you can help me